# Unknown error while installing testrpc in Ubuntu

Tags: truffle, testrpc, ethereumjs

I was trying to install testrpc using `sudo npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc`.

But no ERR messages are shown. Only this is the output:

> ```
> /home/***/.npm-global/bin/testrpc -> /home/***/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/bin/testrpc
> /home/***/.npm-global/lib
> -- ethereumjs-testrpc@3.0.5-- web3@0.16.0
> `-- bignumber.js@2.0.7 (git+https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git#94d7146671b9719e00a09c29b01a691bc85048c2)
> ```

Typing in `testrpc` says

> command not found.

Please help!

OS: Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Add `.npm-global` to your path.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH` Read https://lightrains.com/blogs/fixing-npm-permissions-install-global

Comment: @niksmac I solved this by doing something [similar](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions). I followed Option 2 since my default directory was /usr. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tested on a clean Ubuntu 17.04 and it works.
I had a node v6.10.3

```
ubuntu@1704:~/browser-solidity$ testrpc
EthereumJS TestRPC v3.0.5

Available Accounts
==================
(0) 0x4ab1b67474ce39c8c1759721df2ca71d39793763
(1) 0xadbc646dcc67d3e30e48ca0bbc68089b6f975223
(2) 0x596987a65a9ca1ca878e014e3569cddd489ec911
(3) 0x7baa4193a330f0940487c0c8de40a24d57f228b3
(4) 0xdc2a06af2aac15d65df533d6a1495a50732c852d
(5) 0x05701c81ac2ad9a49cac4971bbe8fde7f16cdab0
(6) 0x806435b01b3b57e3b10fdac8e8990d4cc3876759
(7) 0x4fb64a1ee8d8f9e64582d068e6c98f646b0471e8
(8) 0x00b08b0777b22a89bdda6709178c804b7f8219fb
(9) 0x8d648b84a3cdbd01b5366b9705c9a1da03637d65

Private Keys
==================
(0) 73567e5551c091d0b181048c558543509c3a9c0b63bd7f937abb3ccb4aed4952
(1) a920d6549c9477b058ddc5c43b127cbefc207eb994c0455e752f53eb25ecf5aa
(2) 5df0f04be5770ba0878ccb0fb0c2f53eec6dc09335f9bc6bdb12beb0738a1a73
(3) c5415d0dc0663bcea1206cbcb99ddf4695f76a4610041dc290d4ac3f55c6b166
(4) 6fd811851cc5d1e3caa4877335cf3488bebc7892dd1f73e2149dfc98ba7f800e
(5) 0551e9f93ff0b92846aeba558f5e68a8e5aa5d58b3d509d22f195254b8e5330f
(6) b12ec41a98e5c64fd0e6b72ee5f8e216079a675e83b83d7c8d4b0546bd925cb7
(7) b77b42ed8ae348e0f38ef8859819363c74414e3459437ade07c403ea88dfa4cb
(8) cbc9a401462fcb5063ead0083f086b40bcf6fd5af211090729e779e92783b61d
(9) 53b0d5d08465766f38b66c105f33d8c08155e6eb46590f11707bb57b30237279

HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      desert first wire into cream taxi lottery husband rebuild random bid direct
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Listening on localhost:8545
^C
ubuntu@1704:~/browser-solidity$ node -v
v6.10.3
ubuntu@1704:~/browser-solidity$ whereis testrpc
testrpc: /usr/bin/testrpc
```

also try to install from git

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc.git
cd testrpc
sudo npm install .
```

Comment: I'm getting this error while installing from git: > npm WARN eslint-config-standard@5.3.5 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-promise@>=1.0.8 but none was installed.
> npm WARN ethereumjs-testrpc@3.0.3 No license field.

Comment: @ProgramSpree those are not errors, they are warnings... do you have any errors during the installation... what does `whereis testrpc` command show?

Comment: Yeah, those warnings are irrelevant, I suppose. I solved the problem by changing the default directory.

Answer (score 2):

Run the below cmd:

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the testrpc installation never added the testrpc command to your path, so you cannot call it. Try adding it to you're path.  Search for where your testrpc directory is:

```
sudo find / -name "testrpc"
```

When I executed this search, I got the following:

```
/Users/myusername/Desktop/Projects/node_modules/.bin/testrpc
```

Then add the bin directory holding the testrpc directory to you're path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/josephconnolly/Desktop/Projects/node_modules/.bin
```

At this point, try the testrpc command again.  It fixed my problem on OS X El Capitan